# javascript internationalization and lists (eg [foo,bar,blah] to "foo, bar and blah")

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Is there a javascript internationalization library that supports taking an array of items and converting them to a grammatically correct list based on locale? I'm looking for something that handles the following inputs like below for english.

```
[foo, bar, blah] -> "foo, bar, and blah"
[foo, bar] -> "foo and bar
[foo] -> "foo"
```

Rails supports this as documented in its `to_sentence` method (http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence), so I'm looking for something quite similar. The more popular internationalization frameworks don't seem to support this.

Answer (score 2):

I think [underscore.string](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#tosentence-array-delimiter-lastdelimiter-gt-string) might be what you're looking for.

```
toSentence(["jQuery", "Mootools", "Prototype"]);
// => "jQuery, Mootools and Prototype";

toSentence(["jQuery", "Mootools", "Prototype"], ", ", " unt ");
// => "jQuery, Mootools unt Prototype";
```

Comment: This is nice, so I'm upvoting, but I'm not accepting yet, because I was hoping it would be baked into the interpolation features of a dedicated internationalization library (ie i18next or similar). If nothing like that exists, this could be helpful to roll my own setup.